# Generating random values from a list with replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with 5 values in it and I want to generate 10 randomly chosen values from the original list. I have tried using the random.choices feature, but it returns this in my error code:

```
rythm = random.choices(rythmlist, 10)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? `random.choices()` was added in 3.6

Comment: Also, do you incidentally have a file called random.py in the folder where you run your code?

Comment: BTW, `k` must be a keyword argument 
`random.choices(rythmlist, k=10)` since the declaration is `random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm a bit of a noob, I'm using sublime text, how do I tell what version of python I'm running and how can I update if it's an older version?